# Route link duplica eventos

Tags: javascript, vue3

Estoy realizando un proyecto en vue3 donde tengo que hacer las siguientes cosas:

- Crear una pagina home
- Generar la imagen de 12 cartas con una foto donde salen gatos o perros. Las imagenes, nombre y color de fondo lo cojo a traves d'un archivo .json que mostrare ahora.
- Cuando le doy a una de las cartas, me tiene que llevar a otra pagina donde se muestre la ficha detalle de ese animal.

En este ultimo punto es donde tengo los problemas.

Muestro codigo:

PetList:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="title">Últimas incorporaciones</h2>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3" v-for="pet in pets" :key="pet.id">
        <article class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              :src="pet.image_url"
              alt="{{ pet.name }}"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-main">
              <!-- <h3 class="card-title">{{ pet.nom }}</h3> -->
              <h3 class="card-title">{{ pet.name }}</h3>
              <p class="card-text">{{ pet.location }}</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="card-icons">
              <li>
                <img
                  v-if="pet.species == 'Gato'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_cat.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.species }}"
                />
                <img
                  v-if="pet.species == 'Perro'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_dog.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.species }}"
                />
              </li>
              <li>
                <img
                  v-if="pet.sex == 'Macho'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_male.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.sex }}"
                />
                <img
                  v-if="pet.sex == 'Hembra'"
                  class="card-icon"
                  src="../assets/icons/icon_female.svg"
                  alt="{{ pet.sex }}"
                />
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import json from "@/pets.json";
export default {
  name: "PetList",
  data() {
    return {
      pets: json.data,
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

PetDetail

```
<template>
  <main class="page-home" v-for="pet in pets" :key="pet.id">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="block-featured-content">
        <div class="foto-pet">
          <img class="foto" v-bind:src="pet.image_url" v-bind:alt="pets.name" />
        </div>
        <div class="pet-info">
          <p class="pet-title">
            {{ pet.name }} <span class="blue-text">5 años, Barcelona</span>
          </p>
          <div class="pet-details">
            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Especie</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">{{ pet.species }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Sexo</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">{{ pet.sex }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Medida</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">{{ pet.size }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Cumpleaños</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">{{ pet.birth_date }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Estado</span>
              <span class="pet-detail-data">{{ pet.status }}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="buttom">
            <div class="buttom-adoptar">
              <p class="p-adoptar-text">Lo quiero adoptar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="buttom-compartir">
              <p class="p-compartir-text">Compartir</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pet-history">
        <h3 class="my-history">Mi historia</h3>
        <p class="my-history-text">
          {{ pet.bio }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="pet-extras">
        <div class="pet-extra">
          <h3 class="my-history">Mi personalidad</h3>
          <div class="tags">
            <span class="tag-blue">Bueno con otros perros</span>
            <span class="tag-blue">Cariñoso</span>
            <span class="tag-blue">A veces ladro</span>
            <span class="tag-blue">Amigable con extraños</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pet-extra">
          <h3 class="my-history">Me entregan</h3>
          <div class="pet-details-extra">
            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Vacunado</span>
              <span class="tag-red">No</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Desparasitado</span>
              <span class="tag-green">Si</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Esterilizado</span>
              <span class="tag-green">Si</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-title">Microchip</span>
              <span class="tag-green">Si</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="pet-extra">
          <h3 class="my-history">Tienes que saber</h3>
          <div class="pet-details-extra">
            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Estoy en tratamiento médico</span>
            </div>

            <div class="pet-detail">
              <span class="pet-detail-data">Soy positivo en Leishmania</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <section class="block-actions">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="match-box">
          <p class="match-text">
            Si <b>Darko</b> ya ha sido adoptado/a o no hacéis match, tenemos
            otros animales que te necesitan. Encuéntralos
          </p>
          <form class="search-bar">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Busca a tu nuevo mejor amigo"
              class="form-control search-control"
            />
            <button type="submit" class="btn-icon search-button"></button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
</template>
<script>
import json from "@/pets.json";

export default {
  name: "PetDetail",
  components: {
    // AppFooter,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pets: json.data,
    };
  },
  beforeMounted() {},
  mounted() {
    window.onscroll = function () {
      stickyfy();
    };
    var header = document.getElementById("header");
    function stickyfy() {
      if (window.pageYOffset == 0) {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      } else {
        header.classList.add("sticky");
      }
    }
    const menuIconBar = document.getElementById("menuIconBar");
    const menuIcon = document.getElementById("menuIcon");
    const menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
    function toggleClassActive() {
      if (
        !(
          menuIconBar.classList.contains("menu-icon-cross") ||
          menuIconBar.classList.contains("menu-icon-hamburguer")
        )
      ) {
        menuIconBar.classList.add("menu-icon-cross");
      } else if (menuIconBar.classList.contains("menu-icon-cross")) {
        menuIconBar.classList.remove("menu-icon-cross");
        menuIconBar.classList.add("menu-icon-hamburguer");
      } else if (menuIconBar.classList.contains("menu-icon-hamburguer")) {
        menuIconBar.classList.remove("menu-icon-hamburguer");
        menuIconBar.classList.add("menu-icon-cross");
      }
      menu.classList.toggle("menu-visible");
    }
    menuIcon.addEventListener("click", toggleClassActive);
  },
  methods() {},
};
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss"></style>
```

Route.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

import Home from "@/views/Home.vue";
import NotFound from "@/views/NotFound.vue";
import PetDetail from "@/components/PetDetail.vue";
import Login from "@/views/Login.vue";
import Register from "@/views/Register.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },

  {
    path: "/pet/:id",
    name: "PetDetail",
    component: PetDetail,
  },

  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login,
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
    name: "register",
    component: Register,
  },

  {
    path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFound,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

pets.jason

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Thor",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/thor.png",
            "location": "Barcelona",
            "species": "Gato",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2018-06-01",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": false,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Thor llegó de Montcada y es algo tímido pero con un poco de confianza se deja mimar y acariciar.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Timido",
                "Juguetón"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Pancho",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/pancho.png",
            "location": "Badalona",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2015-12-03",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Pancho es un perro muy obediente y cariñoso. Muy bueno con los niños y otros perros.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con otros perros",
                "Bueno con niños",
                "Cariñoso",
                "Bueno en casa"
            ],
            "info_notes": [
                "Estoy en tratamiento médico",
                "Soy positivo en Leishmania"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Lola",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/lola.png",
            "location": "Barcelona",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Hembra",
            "size": "Pequeño",
            "birth_date": "2019-05-18",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": false,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Lola es buenísima! Le encanta estar con gente y es lo más cariñoso que existe. No ha tenido una vida fácil, fue maltratada casi toda su vida. A pesar de haber tenido un pasado doloroso, ella sólo busca cariño y poder vivir tranquila. Es una perra tranquila, sabe ir con bozal perfectamente y es muy obediente y aprende enseguida.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Me gusta pasear",
                "Me gusta estar en compañía",
                "Cariñoso",
                "Juguetón"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Catiperri",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/catiperri.png",
            "location": "Barcelona",
            "species": "Gato",
            "sex": "Hembra",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2016-03-12",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": false,
                "dewormed": false,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": false
            },
            "bio": "Me llamó Catiperri y llevó mucho tiempo viviendo en la calle, unos 4 años calculo. La vida callejera me ha vuelto desconfiada. Sólo mi alimentadora merecía mi atención y dejaba que me acariciara cuando venía a darme comida y cariño. Soy limpia, uso el arenero y creo que, con un poco de paciencia volveré a confiar.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Cauteloso con extraños",
                "Tímido",
                "Independiente"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Aramis",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/aramis.png",
            "location": "Sabadell",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Pequeño",
            "birth_date": "2019-08-08",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Aramis ha sido encontrado en la calle, llegó flaquito pero no estaba en muy malas condiciones. Por su carácter y su edad, pensamos que ha podido tener familia hasta hace poquito. ",
            "status": "Adoptado",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con otros perros",
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Bueno con otros animales",
                "Me gusta pasear",
                "Cariñoso"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Lucy",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/lucy.png",
            "location": "Montmeló",
            "species": "Gato",
            "sex": "Hembra",
            "size": "Pequeño",
            "birth_date": "2018-02-09",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": false,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Rescatada entre maullando y escondiéndose entre los coches, la pequeña Lucy es una gatita muy juguetona, aventurera, divertida... sociable con otros gatos, tímida con las personas hasta que te conoce y te empieza a ronronear, es un pequeño motorcillo!",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Bueno con niños",
                "Bueno en casa",
                "Cariñoso"
            ],
            "info_notes": [
                "Soy positivo en Leucemia felina"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Bowie",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/bowie.png",
            "location": "Terrassa",
            "species": "Gato",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2015-04-15",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Me llamo Bowie, fuí abandonado y tenía una herida muy grande en el cuello, mi delgadez asustaba y una fractura en la pata que se podía ver el hueso roto. Despues de la cirugía y una larga rehabilitación no logre recuperar la movilidad de mi patita y la llevo encogida, pero hago una vida normal.",
            "status": "Adoptado",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Bueno con niños",
                "Bueno en casa",
                "Cariñoso"
            ],
            "info_notes": [
                "Estoy en tratamiento médico"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Floyd",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/floyd.png",
            "location": "Castelldefels",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Pequeño",
            "birth_date": "2016-10-08",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": false,
                "dewormed": false,
                "sterilized": false,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Floyd es un perro de tamaño mediano, es muy bueno tanto dentro como fuera de casa. Apto con perros, gatos y niños ¿Te animas a adoptarlo?",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con otros perros",
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Bueno en el coche",
                "Cariñoso",
                "Amigable con extraños"
            ],
            "info_notes": [
                "Necesito licencia PPP"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "Murdog",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/murdog.png",
            "location": "Barcelona",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2014-11-01",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Murdog es un perro noble, vigilante muy tranquilo, cariñoso leal y fiel. Ahora está de acogida en un refugio, esperando tener una familia.",
            "status": "En acogida",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con otros perros",
                "Cariñoso",
                "A veces ladro",
                "Amigable con extraños"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "name": "Groucho",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/groucho.png",
            "location": "Mataró",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2016-10-08",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": false,
                "dewormed": false,
                "sterilized": false,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Groucho es un perrito cariñoso, tranquilo, obediente, se lleva muy bien con la gente, con los niños. Es un perrito que sabe ir con correa por lo que seguramente haya vivido en una casa, le gusta defender su hogar y lo suyo ante otros perros.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con otros perros",
                "Bueno con otros animales",
                "Independiente",
                "Bueno con niños"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "Coco",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/coco.png",
            "location": "Barcelona",
            "species": "Gato",
            "sex": "Hembra",
            "size": "Mediano",
            "birth_date": "2018-06-01",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": false,
                "dewormed": false,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": false
            },
            "bio": "Coco es muy cariñosa, juguetóna y curiosa. Muy sociable y divertida.",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con gatos",
                "Bueno con niños",
                "Amigable con extraños"
            ],
            "info_notes": []
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Judas",
            "image_url": "https://petinder-images.netlify.app/judas.png",
            "location": "Terrassa",
            "species": "Perro",
            "sex": "Macho",
            "size": "Grande",
            "birth_date": "2019-04-29",
            "handle_status": {
                "vaccinated": true,
                "dewormed": true,
                "sterilized": true,
                "microchip": true
            },
            "bio": "Busca acogida o adopción junto a su inseparable compañero Duke, no pueden vivir el uno sin el otro",
            "status": "En adopción",
            "personality": [
                "Bueno con otros perros",
                "Bueno con otros animales",
                "Me gusta pasear",
                "Cariñoso",
                "Juguetón"
            ],
            "info_notes": [
                "Adopción conjunta"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

PetList es el archivo que pinta las cartas en home i PetDetail tiene los detalles cuando hacemos click a un animal.

El problema que tengo es que:

1. En home tengo el array de animales pintado pero se reptie muchas veces. Es decir, que los animales me salen repetido.
2. Cuando hago click a una imagen, me lleva a petDetail pero se ven todos los animales uno detras de otro y lo que quiero es ese en concreto.

Que puede fallar?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el contenido de pets.json?

Comment: Buenas, acabo de añadir lo que me comentas. Ayer estube trasteando el codigo y ahora, cuando hago click en una de las cartas de home, me lleva a todas las petdetail de los animales. Es decir uno detras del otro y yo solo quiero que me lleve a esa en concreto.